# Multi array to single array using laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

Mycode:

```
$firstArr[][$titles[0]]  = (string) $data[1];
$firstArr[][$titles[1]]  = (string) $data[2];
$firstArr[][$titles[2]]  = (string) $data[3];
$firstArrIndex = json_encode($firstArr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE). "\r";
```

Laravel output:

```
[{"code":"11000"},{"postal":"0988"},{"prefecture_kana":""}]
```

I want to get array result is:

```
[{"code":"11000","postal":"0988","prefecture_kana":""}]
```

Could you help me:  [{"code":"11000","postal":"0988","prefecture_kana":""}]
like that result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Your response is json response then try this else remove json_decode and use only loop :)

```
$a = '[{"code":"11000"},{"postal":"0988"},{"prefecture_kana":""}]';
$b = json_decode($a);
$array = [];
foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $keySub => $valueSub) {
        $array[$keySub] = $valueSub;
    }
}
dd($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel's [array_collapse](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-collapse) function e.g:

```
array_collapse(json_decode('[{"code":"11000"},{"postal":"0988"},{"prefecture_kana":""}]', true))
```